# How do i make a C++ program open multiple CMD Prompts

Tags: c++, windows

This is kind of an odd question but does anyone know how to make a c++ program open multiple separate CMD prompts? they don't even have to be proper command prompts they can spit out text in a separate CMD like window that's fine. they don't need to talk to each other or do anything more than display text. the only reason I'm not doing this in Batch is because it needs to be a compiled EXE. I know I can run windows commands in c++ with "system(...)" however I'm not sure how to force these to be separate windows. if anyone knows a way to do that I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CreateProcess to rum cmd,and communicate through pipe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me, but let me try:

A single process can have no or exactly one console window. E.g. in Visual Studio, in the linker settings, you can set the subsystem to console, then the console window is opened automatically or you can use [AllocConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/console/allocconsole) to get one. If you need more windows to display text, you have to create these windows by yourself (these windows aren't normal console windows). Another possibility is to start more backgroud processes, each having its own console window to display the text. To start these background processes, use [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) and use for `dwCreationFlags` `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`.

If you have a batch file and want to display multiple console windows, use the `start` command to start your console program to create a new console and disply its output there, e.g.

```
start cmd.exe /k dir
```